# When to call getWarnings() on Connections, Statements, and ResultSets with JDBC?

Tags: java, sql, database, jdbc, warnings

In JDBC the `Connection`, `Statement`, and `ResultSet` types each have a `getWarnings()` method that is specified to produce the first warning associated with objects of that type. The second and subsequent warnings, if they exist, are chained onto the first warning (if *it* even exists, `null` is produced if there are no warnings).

The specs say that warnings associated with objects of these types are cleared after certain actions. For example warnings on a `ResultSet` are cleared when each new row is read.

The `SQLWarning` type is a subtype of `SQLException`. So would the presence of a warning be indicated by an exception? And that exception would be chained to the associated object if the exception's runtime type is `SQLWarning`?

What I'm wondering is this, and it might be driver specific, **how do I know when I should call `getWarnings()` and expect a non-`null` response?** Put another way, is a warning present on a JDBC object and available with `getWarnings()` only after that object has thrown an exception? (and that exception is the warning?)

Should I call `getWarnings()` to look for warnings after every JDBC operation "just to be sure" if my goal is to observe every warning?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`SQLWarning` objects are a subclass of `SQLException` that deal with database access warnings.

Warnings do not stop the execution of an application, as exceptions do; they simply alert the user that something did not happen as planned.

A warning can be reported on a `Connection` object, a `Statement` object (including `PreparedStatement` and `CallableStatement` objects), or a `ResultSet` object.

Each of these classes has a `getWarnings` method, which you must invoke in order to see the first warning reported on the calling object:

```
SQLWarning warning = stmt.getWarnings();
if (warning != null)
{
    System.out.println(\"n---Warning---n\");
    while (warning != null)
    {
        System.out.println(\"Message: \" + warning.getMessage());
        System.out.println(\"SQLState: \" + warning.getSQLState());
        System.out.print(\"Vendor error code: \");
        System.out.println(warning.getErrorCode());
        System.out.println(\"\");
        warning = warning.getNextWarning();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you'd need to getWarnings explicitly if you really want to observe every warning. But why would you want to do such a thing?

Alternatively Spring's JdbcTemplate gives you the option of logging warnings or throwing SQLWarningException when there are warnings. The default behavior is to log warnings because, well, they're warnings. Hopefully this is sufficient for your purposes, too.

Comment: I'm sort of confused by the "why would you want to do such a thing," followed by the idea of logging such warnings through a framework (Spring in this case). Wouldn't the framework do exactly the same thing as hand-written code to observe every warning? I don't see the difference... or are you simply arguing that there's less work on the programmer by using the framework instead of writing the warning reporting code? Surely, from a performance point-of-view, both approaches are executing the same JDBC APIs...

Comment: Yes, the same JDBC methods would be called. I just meant that I too have never found myself checking for warnings explicitly. I also tried to provide you with an easy way to log warnings.

Comment: Sometimes "warnings" can actually be pretty serious. Years ago I worked on a project that used Sybase, and it turned out that inserting a numerical value like "37.000" into a `NUMERIC(n,2)` column would cause that entire row of the insert to be ignored, but would produce a warning, not throw an exception. This was a rare enough occurrence that our tests didn't catch it, and it wasn't until the code was in production for a few weeks that we discovered that some of our inserts were silently failing. We ended up wrapping all of the JDBC objects with wrappers that would throw every `SQLWarning`.